# Laravel insert into multiple tables with one to many relationship

Tags: laravel, insert, eloquent, one-to-one, laravel-5.5

I have two tables, one is `items` table which has the description of the item like (category, name, price ..etc).

And that table has a relation `one-to-one` with another table called `prices` table, which represent the price of each item. So each `item` has one price.

Now I have a form for adding items (one or multiple rows):

- item_id(int), name(text), price(number).
- item_id(int), name(text), price(number).
- item_id(int), name(text), price(number).

I want to insert those items directly to database using eloquent relationship tool, here's what I did:

```
foreach ($request as $key => $value) {
    $item  = [];
    $price = [];
    $item['item_id'] = $value['item_id'];
    $item['name']    = $value['name'][$i];
    $price['price']  = $value['price'][$i];
    Item::create($item);
    Price::create($price);
}
```

Is there's a better way to insert the request directly to both tables using eloquent, without creating arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [createMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) method for that. [See Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)

```
$items = $request->get('items');
Item::createMany($items);

$prices = $request->get('prices');
Price::createMany($prices);
```

Comment: Do I need to create arrays as I mentioned, or I can just pass the full request, as the both related to each other.

Comment: You have to create arrays for input. But by this way, you don't need loops and multiple insert queries.